# no sound devices listed after system update oct. 8/ 22: pipewire, wire plumber installed and working perviously

Tags: pipewire

I did an upgrade today, noticed pipewire and others upgraded but did not watch carefully. now I have no audio in or out devices listed. HP laptop.

```
systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-pulse wireplumber pulseaudio
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-10-08 19:03:18 CST; 10min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 1251 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 28567)
     Memory: 6.1M
        CPU: 55ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewi>
             └─1251 /usr/bin/pipewire

Oct 08 19:03:18 rjvmain systemd[1243]: Started PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Oct 08 19:03:18 rjvmain pipewire[1251]: mod.rt: Can't find xdg-portal: (null)
Oct 08 19:03:18 rjvmain pipewire[1251]: mod.rt: found session bus but no portal

○ pipewire-pulse.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit pipewire-pulse.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)

● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; vendor>
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-10-08 19:03:18 CST; 10min ago
   Main PID: 1253 (wireplumber)
lines 1-23
```

if anyone has a recommendation, would be greatly appreciated. I have tried restarting services, etc. nothing is working, beyond my knowledge, tks for any help.

Comment: What OS did you upgrade?

Comment: ubuntu 22.04.1 , sorry should have included that

Comment: Try to install `xdg-desktop-portal`

Comment: Please add additional details (ie. your release) to your question.

Comment: xdg-desktop-portal already installed

Comment: the sound card is listed, 
sudo lspci

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)

Comment: there seems to be some similar pipewire issue as listed here:https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/pipewire-issues-since-updating/26464/2 and here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pipewire/+bug/1991934

Comment: I am using cinnamon 5.2.7

Answer (score 3):

For me helped:

```
systemctl --user start pipewire-pulse.service
wait ~30 sec
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

I have created bug-report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pipewire/+bug/1993739

Answer (score 2):

As suggested on [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pipewire/+bug/1993739/comments/8) on the bug-report created by Vsevolod Gromov, you can add the pipewire-upstream PPA, change to use the jammy distribution and update :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream 
sudo sed -i 's/kinetic/jammy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pipewire-debian-ubuntu-pipewire-upstream-kinetic.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then reboot.

This repo will have to be removed once the bug will be fixed, so you can subscribe to be notified of changes on the bug ticket.